# Incrementing a number and then setting back after fixed records arre entered?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, auto-increment

Actuallt I want to set a varaiable as 6 digit number, incrementing it and resetting it back whent the record reaches  999999. I want to increment the value only when I perform a certain call to the web service through my client that is written in Java. Can you please suggest any method for doing? Any other way then creating a database and entering the value in that and then flushing the values when the count reaches 999999.
Thanks

Comment: Unable to understand the difficulty from your question. incrementing a value on webservice call and resetting it on reaching a limit seems to be simple and can be done by basic conditional operators.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write an example in a singleton but I recommend using spring or container equivalent to use 1 single bean to do this.

```
public class Counter {
    private static Counter instance;
    private static int COUNT_MAX_VALUE = 1000000;
    public static synchronized Counter getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Counter();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // -- end of static features --
    private int counter;
    public Counter() {
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    // return result
    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return counter;
    }

    // increment by 1, then return result
    public synchronized int addAndGetCount() {
        addCount();
        return getCount();
    }

    // increment by 1
    public synchronized int addCount() {
        if (++counter >= COUNT_MAX_VALUE) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joris, 
How can Spring be used, can you please help? I am new to Spring and my application uses Spring framework.

Comment: That I cannot help you with, which is why I gave the singleton solution. If you use spring framework then there is a lot of online documentation available for you to read. I would suggest reading up on the framework you are using.